# Inner join with count and group by

Tags: t-sql, count, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have 2 tables

**Timetable :**
pupil_id, staff_id, subject, lesson_id

**Staff_info :**
staff_id, surname

The timetable table contains 1000s of rows because each student's ID is listed under each period they do.

I want to list all the teacher's names, and the number of lessons they do (count). So I have to do SELECT with DISTINCT.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TIMETABLE.STAFF_ID,
                COUNT(TIMETABLE.LESSON_ID),
                STAFF.SURNAME
FROM STAFF
INNER JOIN TIMETABLE ON TIMETABLE.STAFF_ID = STAFF.STAFF_ID
GROUP BY TIMETABLE.STAFF_ID
```

However I get the error:

> Column 'STAFF.SURNAME' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: `(TIMETABLE.STAFF_ID = STAFF.STAFF_ID` - is the parantheses a typo?

Comment: Yes sorry it is a typo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
SELECT s.STAFF_ID, COUNT(tt.LESSON_ID),
       s.SURNAME
FROM STAFF s INNER JOIN
     TIMETABLE tt
    ON tt.STAFF_ID = s.STAFF_ID
GROUP BY s.STAFF_ID, s.SURNAME;
```

Notes:

- You don't need `DISTINCT` unless there are duplicates in either table.  That seems unlikely with this data structure, but if a staff member could have two of the same lesson, you would use `COUNT(DISTINCT tt.LESSON_ID)`.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- You should include `STAFF.SURNAME` in the `GROUP BY` as well as the id.
- I have a preference for taking the `STAFF_ID` column from the table where it is the primary key.
- If you wanted staff with no lessons, you would change the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you @gordon-linoff

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT T.STAFF_ID,
       T.CNT,
       S.SURNAME
FROM STAFF S
JOIN (
    SELECT STAFF_ID, CNT = COUNT(/*DISTINCT*/ LESSON_ID)
    FROM TIMETABLE
    GROUP BY STAFF_ID
) T ON T.STAFF_ID = S.STAFF_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
SELECT DISTINCT si.staff_id, surname, COUNT(lesson_id) OVER(PARTITION BY staff_Id)
FROM Staff_info si
INNER JOIN Timetable tt ON si.staff_id = tt.staff_id
```

Answer (score 1):

When using Aggregate function(Count, Sum, Min, Max, Avg) in the Select column's list, any other columns that are in the Select column's list but not in a aggregate function, should be mentioned in GROUP BY section too. So you need to change your query as follow and add STAFF.SURNAME to GROUP BY section too:

```
SELECT TIMETABLE.STAFF_ID,
            COUNT(TIMETABLE.LESSON_ID),
            STAFF.SURNAME
FROM STAFF
INNER JOIN TIMETABLE ON TIMETABLE.STAFF_ID = STAFF.STAFF_ID
GROUP BY TIMETABLE.STAFF_ID,STAFF.SURNAME
```

Distinct is useless also in your scenario. and also as you are going to show the teachers name and Count lessons, you do not need to add TIMETABLE.STAFF_ID to Select's column's list,, but it should remain in Group By section to prevent duplicate names.

```
SELECT COUNT(TIMETABLE.LESSON_ID),
            STAFF.SURNAME
FROM STAFF
INNER JOIN TIMETABLE ON TIMETABLE.STAFF_ID = STAFF.STAFF_ID
GROUP BY TIMETABLE.STAFF_ID,STAFF.SURNAME
```

You may need to take a look at [this W3C post](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) for more info